# React-Native | drawerContent props.progress return undefined

Tags: react-native, animation, react-navigation

I'm trying to buid a react-native application. I followed this tutorial in order to make the drawer part : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NV48FIIWaN0&t=1331s&ab_channel=ByProgrammers .

In this tutorial, he is using props.progress to update the progress status in order to compute the animation. I have nearly the same code and mine isn't working. props.progress return undefined.

Please find here my code :

```
const DrawerNavigator = ({route}) =>{

    const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(new Animated.Value(0))

    const scale = Animated.interpolateNode(progress,{
        inputRange : [0,1],
        outputRange : [0,0.8]
    })

    const borderRadius = Animated.interpolateNode(progress,{
        inputRange : [0,1],
        outputRange : [0,25]
    })

    const animatedStyle = {transform:[{scale}]}
    
    return(
        <View style = {styles.mainContainer}>
            <Drawer.Navigator
                
                initialRouteName = "FableReader"
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false,
                    drawerStyle : [styles.drawerContainer],
                    drawerType : "slide",
                    overlayColor : "transparent",
                    sceneContainerStyle : [styles.sceneContainer],
                    
                }}
                drawerContent = {({...props})=>{
                        setTimeout(()=>{
                            setProgress(props.progress)
                        },0)
                        return(
                            <CustomContent {...props} route = {route}></CustomContent>
                        )
                    }}
            >
                <Drawer.Screen name="FableReader">{props => <FableReaderScreen {...props}/>}</Drawer.Screen>
                <Drawer.Screen name="LexiqueFable">{props => <LexiqueScreen {...props}/>}</Drawer.Screen>
                <Drawer.Screen name="QCM">{props => <QCMScreen {...props}/>}</Drawer.Screen>
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </View>
```

If you know what is wrong you're my hero !

Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 1):

DrawerContent **props.progress** worked in React navigation 5. It has been removed in React navigation 6.

In React navigation 6 you can use **useDrawerProgress**. By default it returns 0 or 1. To get animation use **useLegacyImplementation**:

```html
<Drawer.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
        drawerPosition: 'left',
        drawerType: 'slide',
        headerShown: false,
        overlayColor: 'transparent',
        drawerStyle: {
            flex: 1,
            width: '75%',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        },
        sceneContainerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        },
    }}
    initialRouteName="Home"
    drawerContent={props => <Sidebar {...props} />}
    useLegacyImplementation
>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

```html
import React from "react"
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

/* Animation */
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated'

/* Drawer */
import { useDrawerProgress } from "@react-navigation/drawer"


const Home = props => {

    const progress = useDrawerProgress()

    const scale = Animated.interpolateNode(progress, {
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [1, 0.8],
        extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })

    const borderRadius = Animated.interpolateNode(progress, {
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 30],
        extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })

    const style = { borderRadius, transform: [{ scale }] }

    return (
        <Animated.View style={[style, styles.box]}>
            {/* Your content */}
        </Animated.View>
    )
}

export default Home




const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your animation-related code needs to be inside your `CustomContent` component, not inside `DrawerNavigator`.

Then remove this:

```js
const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(new Animated.Value(0))
```

And replace it with:

```js
const progress = useDrawerProgress();
```

Where you import `useDrawerProgress` from `@react-navigation/drawer`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I can't but my animation-related code in customContent because i need to send it to my drawer.screen. Then I've tried to replace my useState with useDrawerProgress but it makes instantly crash expo when in customcontent and return a Hook error when in drawerNavigator.

Comment: What are you animating? `useDrawerProgress` can only be used inside a drawer navigator, not outside

Comment: I'm trying to do the rescale animation of the screen when the drawer is opened. That's why i need the animation code to be outside the drawer content

Comment: useDrawerProgress(); is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

You should put it inside your Layout component for the navigator, FableReader. And also, you should use hook -> useDrawerProgress

```
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import React from 'react';
import { useDrawerProgress } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';


const FableReader= () => {
  const progress = useDrawerProgress();

  const scale = Animated.interpolateNode(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0.8],
  });
  const borderRadius = Animated.interpolateNode(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 25],
  });

  const animatedStyle = {
    borderRadius,
    transform: [{ scale }],
    overflow: 'hidden',
  };

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        ...animatedStyle,
      }}
    >
      <Text>FableReader page</Text>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default FableReader;
```

Comment: its not working properly

Comment: Can you provide an error message? It's working fine inside my app.

Comment: useDrawerProgress only update 0 and 1 doesn't show any progress in between. I have console the value of progress its not updating propely. Can you please provide link to your code(example). Thanks!

Comment: Of course, here is the link to the project:
https://github.com/AleksandarBisevac/react-native-food-delivery-app

Comment: this dosn't contain any code, can you check and update it?

Comment: can you check and update your repo?? it doesn't contain any code.

Comment: https://github.com/AleksandarBisevac/react-native-food-delivery-app/tree/feature-4-ab/filter-modal

Hm, try again, should be good.

Comment: using useDrawerProgress in the main layout is not possible. throws an error